# c# how to change the color of rectangle every 5 seconds

Tags: c#, oop, timer, colors, drawrectangle

i have a program that has bouncing squares within a form, i also have to make it so that every 5 seconds the drawn squares change color, i have a timer to update a listbox on the coordinates of each box and a second timer with the interval of 5000 to change the color of the square. now i am trying to figure out how exactly do i change the color of the squares with the timer, i have a method called `colorchange` with a property called `rectcolor`

```
 private Color Rectcolor { get; set; }

 }
    public Color Colorchange()
    {
        Rectcolor =  Color.FromArgb(randcolor.Next(256), randcolor.Next(256), randcolor.Next(256));
        return Rectcolor;
    }
```

in `Form1` i have the timer2 tick event with a foreach going through the boxes

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random Randcolor = Box.randcolor;
    Random Rand = Box.rand;
    List<Box> Boxes = new List<Box>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

    }
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Box tmp in Boxes)
        {
            tmp.Colorchange();
        }
    }
```

when i run the program nothing happens with the moving rectangles, how do i make `colorchange` actually change the color of the rectangle?

Full Box Class Code

```
class Box
{
    protected Rectangle myRectangle;
    protected int xStep;
    protected int yStep;
    protected Form pForm;
    protected Label myLocation;
    protected Color myColor;
    public static Random rand = new Random();
    public static Random randcolor = new Random();

    public Box(int x, int y, int s, Form pF)
    {
        myColor = new Color();
        myColor = Colorchange();
        myLocation = new Label();
        myLocation.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        myLocation.Left = x;
        myLocation.Top = y;
        myLocation.ForeColor = Colorchange();
        pF.Controls.Add(myLocation);
        pForm = pF;
        myRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, s, s);
        myRectangle.X = x;
        myRectangle.Y = y;
        xStep = rand.Next(1, 15);
        yStep = rand.Next(1, 15);
    }

    public int X { get { return myRectangle.X; } }
    public int Y { get { return myRectangle.Y; } }
    private int Width { get { return myRectangle.Width; } }
    private int Height { get { return myRectangle.Height; } }
    private Color Rectcolor { get; set; }
    public void Move()
    {
        myRectangle.X += xStep;
        myRectangle.Y += yStep;
        if (myRectangle.X <= 0)
            xStep *= -1;
        if (myRectangle.X + myRectangle.Width >= pForm.ClientSize.Width)
            xStep *= -1;
        if (myRectangle.Y <= 0)
            yStep *= -1;
        if (myRectangle.Y + myRectangle.Height >= pForm.ClientSize.Height)
            yStep *= -1;
        //if (myRectangle.X >500)
        //    xStep *= -1;

    }
    public Color Colorchange()
    {
        Rectcolor =  Color.FromArgb(randcolor.Next(256), randcolor.Next(256), randcolor.Next(256));
        return Rectcolor;
    }


    public static bool Bounce(Box One, Box Two)
    {
        if (One.X + One.Width < Two.X)
            return false;
        if (Two.X + Two.Width < One.X)
            return false;
        if (One.Y + One.Height < Two.Y)
            return false;
        if (Two.Y + Two.Height < One.Y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    //public void collision()
    //{

    //    xStep *= -1;
    //    yStep *= -1;
    //}
    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue), myRectangle);

        myLocation.Top = myRectangle.Y -15;
        myLocation.Left = myRectangle.X+(myRectangle.Width/4);
        myLocation.Text = myRectangle.X.ToString() + ", " + myRectangle.Y.ToString();

    }
```

i start the timer on the buttone click, i will give you form1

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random Randcolor = Box.randcolor;
    Random Rand = Box.rand;
    List<Box> Boxes = new List<Box>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Box tmp = new Box(100, 100, 40);
        // Boxes.Add(tmp);
        for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
        {
            Boxes.Add(
                new Box(
                    Rand.Next(100 + x * 10, this.ClientSize.Width - 100),
                Rand.Next(100 + x * 10, this.ClientSize.Height - 100),
                Rand.Next(100 + x * 15), this));

            //Boxes.Add(new Box(100 + x * 10, 100 + x * 10, x * 15, this));

        }
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer2.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Box tmp in Boxes)
        {
            tmp.Draw(e.Graphics);

        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Box tmp in Boxes)
        {
            tmp.Move();
            listBox1.Items.Add(tmp.X + ", " + tmp.Y);
        }
        this.Invalidate(false);


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Box tmp in Boxes)
        {
            tmp.Colorchange();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please provide the code for your `Box` class.

Comment: it has been updated

Comment: Where do you start the timers?

Comment: on the button click that creates the boxes, added in form 1

Answer (score 0):

Your `ColorChange()` method never really 'applies' the new color to the `Rectangle` object within your `Box` class.

Within your `Box` class you need a new `Graphics` object. You could set it as field or pass it as parameter for the constructor, as you are using it within the `Draw()` method anyways.

```
        private Graphics g;

        ...

        public Box(int x, int y, int s, Form pF)
        {
            g = pF.CreateGraphics();

            ...
        }
```

You will also have to modify your `ColorChange()` method, so that the `Rectangle` gets filled to the desired color:

```
public Color Colorchange()
{
    this.Rectcolor = Color.FromArgb(randcolor.Next(256), randcolor.Next(256), randcolor.Next(256));

    // You need to fill the rectangle with the desired color again
    this.g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.Rectcolor), this.myRectangle);
    return Rectcolor;
}
```

Comment: the rectangles change but only for a second, it is getting redrawn as blue again

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot rebuild your problem, because of the missing XAML and code for timers. Do your timers tick every second?

Comment: timer1 has an interval of 100 and timer2 has an interval of 5000

Comment: Both of your timers access and modify the same list, probably thats the issue. Try to comment out the timer that moves the rectangles around (timer2) and check if the colors are changing correctly now.

Comment: yes commenting out the timer that enables the move method does change the colors properly, should i be creating a new list for the other timer to avoid this problem?

Comment: You could use a boolean flag (as field) and move all the code of timer1, to timer2, add a if-statement around the code of timer1. Something like: if (flag) { code of timer1 + this.changeCol = false; } and within the timer1_tick(..) you just set that flag to true with every tick: this.flag= true;

Answer (score 0):

```
g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue), myRectangle);
```

this line draws a blue rectangle. Whatever color you've set to "myColor", it draws blue. Changing this to

```
g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(myColor), myRectangle);
```

should fix your issue.